# Hibernate and special chars

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

Imagine I have a database with one table, this table has only one field named "word" and some other data, imagine also that user can search data by typing contents of this field. I have a lot of words on this table with Spanish accents.

### Word examples

ácido

autobús

camión

### Question

If user searches for "acido" or "ácido" words the query will return "ácido" row. How do this with Hibernate?

### Edit

I'm using Oracle 10g as RDBMS and Hibernate named query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm using Oracle TRANSLATE function, in a named query similar to this:

```
  <query name="queryName">
  <![CDATA[
        FROM Table
        WHERE 
          upper(TRANSLATE(nivell_1,'ÀàÉÈéèÍíÓóÒòÚú','AaEEeeIiOoOoUu')) LIKE
          upper(TRANSLATE(nivell_1,'ÀàÉÈéèÍíÓóÒòÚú','AaEEeeIiOoOoUu'))
  ]]>         
  </query>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate will simply pass the search through to the database. If your database is set up to recognise these differently, then so will Hibernate.

In SQL Server, you can set a collation for the column (or table or database - choice is yours) to make that data accent insensitive. Suspect there are similar mechanisms in other DBMSs, and I would say that will be your best approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think you are talking about this Oracle specific mechanism: http://www.rampant-books.com/10g_77.htm